# Packaging FireFox into Installer

Tags: firefox, packages, installer

Is there a way to package FireFox with all of it's configurations and extensions into an installer package to redistribute?

I would like to cut back on having to setup FireFox the same on every system it gets installed on.

Answer (score 0):

The Firefox **install_directory\browser\defaults\profile** (if it exists) is the template directory that Firefox uses to populate a [new profile](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Profile_folder). It is similar to the Windows **Default User**, or Gnu/Linux **/etc/skel** concepts. The contents inside (if any) are copied to a new profile, and Firefox immediately starts using it (if valid/relevant). "New profile" means: a user starting Firefox for the very first time, or a user with an existing profile [starting Firefox in a new profile](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profile-manager-create-and-remove-firefox-profiles), or an action like Reset Firefox.

To hardcode this into the Firefox installer: Using [7-Zip](http://7-zip.org/) for example, extract the installer, and create the **\browser\defaults\profile** directory structure inside **core**. Next, start Firefox in a [new profile](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profile-manager-create-and-remove-firefox-profiles), make the required changes in Firefox **Tools** (Alt + T) > **Options**, and [about:config](http://kb.mozillazine.org/About:config), install the required extensions via Firefox **Tools** (Alt + T) > **Add-ons** > [**Get Add-ons**, and/or the **Search** bar on the top right], open the profile folder via Firefox **Help** (Alt + H) > **Troubleshooting Information** > **Show Folder**, and exit Firefox.

Finally, copy the required folders/files from the opened profile folder into **\core\browser\defaults\profile**. [Here's](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profiles-where-firefox-stores-user-data#w_what-information-is-stored-in-my-profile) a list of the [folders/files](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Profile_folder_-_Firefox#Files_and_folders_in_the_profile) that can be potentially used. A quick way to decide is to mentally separate the folders/files into two categories: user-related and Firefox-related, so user-related folders/files would include extensions, chrome, cert8.db, cookies.sqlite etc. and can be used as templates whereas Firefox-related folders/files would include healthreport, minidumps, times.json etc. and should be ignored.

In our example we would need to copy **prefs.js** which holds the changes made via Options and about:config, and also the **extensions** folder which contains the installed extensions. One thing to note is that it would be good to open **prefs.js** in an editor like [Notepad++](http://www.notepad-plus-plus.org/) to remove the path and user specific information. Also, files like addons.*, extensions.* shouldn't be copied. These will be created including user/path info correctly for the end users by Firefox.

As for packaging there are various methods:

Using 7-Zip zip the customized **core** and **setup.exe** in a top-level .7z archive (.7z file/zip format) and convert it into a .exe setup using [7-Zip SFX Maker](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sfx-maker/) for example.

A further option (if needed) would be to wrap this .exe into a .msi (Windows Installer) setup using for example [EXE to MSI Converter](http://www.exetomsi.com/download.php).

Yet another option would be to package an existing Firefox **install_directory** including **\browser\defaults\profile**, as a .msi using [wItem](http://www.witemsoft.com/).

Still another option is to run Firefox via the network. Install and customize Firefox on a central PC, create and populate the **install_directory\browser\defaults\profile**, and finally distribute the firefox.exe shortcut to the other systems' Desktop and/or Start Menu. Also, enable offline cache for better performance and to avoid network congestion/storms.

Also, if you have a Configuration/Systems Management application (a third-party suite, or Microsoft SMS/SCCM), it would be possible to just point to the setup.exe as the program to run, and the Management application itself does the necessary transferring and/or packaging of the (now customized) **core**, and **setup.exe** and executes setup.exe on the clients. (setup.exe is the actual Firefox installer. The downloaded Firefox installer itself actually invokes setup.exe, and optionally passes any arguments to it.)

[about:config Entries](http://kb.mozillazine.org/About:config_entries), [Config Descriptions extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/config-descriptions/)